# tesseract-ocr `./configure` triggering Error "leptonica not found"

Tags: install-from-source, configure

I was trying to install `tesseract-ocr` using these commands:

```
auto-apt run ./configure
make
checkinstall
```

Auto-apt and apt-file are installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 and up to date.

However, during the ./configure process I'm encountering the following error:

```
checking for strerror... yes
checking for vsnprintf... yes
checking for gethostname... yes
checking for strchr... yes
checking for memcpy... yes
checking for acos... yes
checking for asin... yes
checking for leptonica... configure: error: leptonica not found
```

Here is the full configure code: [Code on Paste past.ofcode.org](http://paste.ofcode.org/?edit=7DzxMQD9JecCiavnGZYpYU)

I have already installed the 'leptonica-progs' package but still encountering the same error.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Almost all programs that compile with a `./configure` (such as this one, although it's triggered during the `auto-apt` process) are *not* looking for the actual binaries of the program the dependencies checks refer to.  Instead, such systems are looking for development libraries and header files, and not the binaries.  Those are usually kept in a separate package with a `-dev` suffix, in a similar name.  To that end, we need to find the corresponding development headers for the library.

What `leptonica-progs` which you installed contains are sample programs for the Leptonica library, and not the actual headers/library files.  Searching the [packages system under Trusty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=leptonica&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all), I think you will need to install the `libleptonica-dev` package to install the actual headers and library files for the library itself.

Run `sudo apt-get install libleptonica-dev` and then run the `./configure` line again, and it shouldn't be triggering on the leptonica dependency anymore.

Comment: Please highlight the last paragraph or put it as first paragraph.

Comment: @user2672299 I don't find either of those options to really improve anything for the post...